# user id not the same as user post id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have an express app where you can make and view posts. I am trying to make it so an edit icon appears next to the users post if they made it. I've tried to do this with an handlebar helper.

```
editIcon: function (user, loggedUser, floating = true) {
console.log(user, loggedUser);
if (user._id.toString() == loggedUser._id.toString()) {
  if (floating) {
    return `<div>edit icon</div>`;
  }
} else {
  return '';
}
```

},

Basically user is the user._id. loggedUser is the id inside the post and it's the same as the user id.

This is what my handlebar looks like:

```
  {{#each posts}}
    <div class="post-extra">
      <div class="card-image">
        <!-- User is the logged in user and then post id (_id) -->
        {{{editIcon user _id}}}
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="user-link">{{user.username}}</a>
      <h2>{{postTitle}}</h2>
    </div>
  {{else}}
  <p>No posts to display</p>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

The problem is that when I console log user and loggedUser, the id's returned are different. In my mongodb though, the user id and the user id inside the post are the same.

My post and user objects:

Post:

```
_id:ObjectId("5f8523d8b58f4919908e3895") <-- this is being returned..
postTitle:"Test post"
postBody:"<div>stuff</div>"
user:ObjectId("5f8522c9c0ec222ea4b7c8c0") <-- instead of this
createdAt:2020-10-13T03:49:44.333+00:00
__v:0
```

User:

```
  _id: ObjectId("5f8522c9c0ec222ea4b7c8c0"), // User id 
  username: 'test',
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  password: 'hashed password here',
  createdAt: 2020-10-13T03:45:13.018Z,
  __v: 0
```

Comment: Why is `user` passed to `editIcon` twice in `{{{editIcon user user _id}}}`?

Comment: @76484 Typo. Just fixed it now. Everything in the post still applies though and is the same.

Comment: What `id` values get logged and what values are you expecting.

Comment: @76484 user._id logs the whole user object including the id. Logged user logs the post id. In my post I have a user with the userid. I want to see if the user._id matches the user id inside the post, if it does then display an edit icon next to that post.

Comment: I don't see how `user._id` could hold the whole user object. But it sounds like the `_id` argument to the helper is the ID of the Post. You should be able to pass the Post's `user` property to the helper and get the ID from that. Perhaps if you posted the data - the Post and User objects - you would be able to get more specific help.

Comment: You're right, user._id should not hold the user object, when I console log it returns the id it was a mistake on my part. I think the problem is i'm not getting the id's properly. The reason I say this is because I get the id from the post instead of the user's id. I just updated my post with both the user and post objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are calling your `editIcon` helper as `{{{editIcon user _id}}}`, you are passing the `user` of the `post` and the `_id` of the `post`. This is incorrect because what you want to compare is the `user` of the post to the `user` of the request (the logged-in `user`).

From the example you have provided it is not clear whether you have access to the `user` of the request in your template. *If* you do, it certainly won't be nested in a `post` object, so you will need a path to step up a context or two to access it. The result would look something like:

```
{{{editIcon user ../user}}}
```

In this example, the logged-in `user` is a sibling of the `posts` Array, but your data structure may be different.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/4Lo9zvj3/) for your reference.

Comment: First I want to say thank you for spending this much time on my problem. So I've looked at the fiddle provided and my data structure is the same as the example. However, when I add ._id to logged in user it becomes undefined. I'm populating the page with users and have `  user: {
    // Connects user to posts
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'LocalUser',
  },` in my posts schema. I really feel like i've tried everything.

Comment: In this case, I would suggest logging the logged-in user to see what properties it has.